# Disable DataSourceAutoConfiguration Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have a library that makes use of spring-jdbc, the library contains common utility methods that need to be standardized across multiple projects.
The library when used in other spring boot application causes the project to fail with no bean on type DataSourceConfuguration Exception.

I have read tips to exclude DataSourceConfiguration on @SpringBootApplication but that would mean making change on every application that uses the library regardless of whether the application needs a datasource or not.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyConfiguration {
}
```

The other option is to exclude DataSourceConfiguration in spring.factories of the library itself, but then it would stop the autoconfig ability of any application using the library and will have to manually define DataSource.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Is there a possible way to make this situation work for the library and any other project that wants to use the library but doesn't have to define a datasource and still function like a normal Spring Boot Application ?

Answer (score 1):

The below is from Spring Documentation

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyConfiguration {
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

Comment: Like mentioned in para#2, this exclusion will have to be done by every application implementing the library and this situation is not ideal.